# Monitoring a running process via command line

Tags: linux, debugging, process

So, lets say there is a running web server process or a python process that is running on my linux machine.

Based on my knowledge, the best way to monitor this process is to do:

-> strace -p "process_id"

Now, this is one way that I know would be helpful.

Questions:

- If I use /proc/process_id, I am not exactly sure what to look at to know whats happening within the process ??
- Any other ways in linux that can be used to attach to the process id ?
- How about Mac, I think Dtrace is a way but dont know how to use it ?

Comment: "monitor this process" is quite a broad topic. As you've mentioned, `strace` is one possibility - it traces system calls. It has a cousin `ltrace` for tracing library calls, or `gdb` for general debugging of all sorts. `dtrace` is good for many things as well. Many tools, some more specialized than others. You'd probably do better defining exactly what it is you are attempting to do...

Comment: Although gdb is a good tool for general debugging, I dont think gdb comes preinstalled. What I am trying to do is I want to attach to a running process and see whats happening at the kernal/system and the IO level, if there is a way. For eg: we can take a webserver, now how can I know what the webserver is servicing at any point in time ???

Comment: If you want to know what requests a web server is handling, the web server logging functions are probably the best place to start. Things like `strace` and `ltrace` will help you know all the things the web server has to do in order to handle those requests, but that's a lower level - things like open a socket, spawn a thread, read some directories and files, write to the logs, send some data back, etc. That may be more info than you can comfortably sort through if all you want to know is what requests are being handled...